# Tracking Issues

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

I've just started getting into camera tracking and ran into several issues.
After detecting features, automatically laying more than 8 trackers, manually trimming and refining the focal length, I managed to get a solver error of 0.32px. Satisfied with the number, I go to Scene setup for "Set as Background" and "Setup Tracking Scene".

The issues come into how the "Setup Tracking Scene" doesn't show any of the tracking markers into the 3d viewport/Layout Tab. I compensated by pressing "Link Empty to Track". Then I wanted to place the generated 'ground' plane using the automatic orientation on "Wall" button after selecting 3 trackers, resulting for a bad displacement. Literally shifted the camera far away from the plane. So I tried to mess around with the orientation manually and playing the animation with the default cube shows so much jitter that it's practically unstable.

Anyone else experienced this? Any good videos I can watch (besides CGMatter) for more indept tutorials?
Also, has anyone been unable to manipulate the extra features found in the bottom left corner of the screen when "Detect Features" has been selected. I wanted to add more trackers and spread them apart but blender only lets me stick with default.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to confirm that for someone new to camera tracking/solving, the CGMatter tutorials are great but don’t seem to suffice. There seems to be a lack of in-depth tutorials when it comes to the step of integrating the trackers into the 3d-layout.

Tracking features seems relatively problem-free, actually, in comparison.

Please let us know if you found what you were looking for!